# Trouble with mainUIThread and database acces

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-room, dao

I have function where i need to get from db data and put in UI through adapter
but if i make in second Thread i catch exception

**Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

and if i make in mainThread i catch exception

**Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.**

(db.dao.drinks() - get all drinks from database Room and return MutableList< Drink >)

I solved the problem but this way so bad, i guess. How to do it right?

```
private fun loadDrinks(){ 
        Thread {
            historyDrinkList = db.dao().drinks()
            this@MainActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
                if (historyDrinkList.isNotEmpty())
                    this@MainActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable { empty.text = null })
                else
                    clHistory.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

                adapter?.updateData(historyDrinkList) })
        }.start()

    }
```

Adapter

```
class MainAdapter (private val onDrinkListener: OnDrinkListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.MainViewHolder>(){

    private var drinks = ArrayList<DBDrink>()
    private val TAG = "MainAdapter"
    private var idDrink: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MainViewHolder {
        val binding: ItemDrinkBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), R.layout.item_drink, parent, false)
        return MainViewHolder(binding, onDrinkListener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return drinks.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(drinks[position])
    }

    fun updateData(drink: List<DBDrink>) {
        this.drinks.clear()
        this.drinks.addAll(drink)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class MainViewHolder(private val binding: ItemDrinkBinding, private val onDrinkListener: OnDrinkListener) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), View.OnClickListener {


        fun bind(drink: DBDrink) {
            binding.drinkName.text = drink.strDrink
            binding.drinkImage.load(drink.strDrinkThumb){
                transformations(RoundedCornersTransformation(25f))
            }
            idDrink.add(drink.idDrink)
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            onDrinkListener.onDrinkClick(adapterPosition, idDrink)

        }


    }

    interface OnDrinkListener{
        fun onDrinkClick(position: Int, idDrink: ArrayList<String>)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is basically the right approach. You get the data from the database in a background thread and update the `View`s on the main (UI) thread. You can, however, simplify your code as you don't need the second `runOnUiThread()`:

```
    Thread {
        historyDrinkList = db.dao().drinks()
        this@MainActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
            if (historyDrinkList.isNotEmpty())
                empty.text = null
            else
                clHistory.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

            adapter?.updateData(historyDrinkList) })
    }.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a ViewModel first with your MutableList.

So you can use the ViewModel in your code and don't have to handle it with a Thread:

```
viewModel.getAllDrinks.observe(this, Observer { drinks -> adapter.updateData(drinks)}
```

In here you can update your Views too.

Comment: OP doesn't actually say they have (or know) what a viewmodel is, so you should include that explanation and code in your answer as well :) besides, what you're describing is likely to be liveData and not a ViewModel